# java.util.zip.ZipException: while overriding a file/class from a gradle dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

In one of the android projects, I'm using Picasso, Glide, OkHttp etc libraries. Now, I'm seeing a few crashes happening in these library codes. I've fixed the code but I had to include the library code into my android project as a modular dependency.

Is there a way to include only the files I'm changing in my project (in the same package structure, of course) and rest can come from respective gradle dependency.

In other words, is there a way to exclude a particular file from gradle dependency and have a local copy of the file to be used instead.

When I tried to keep both, the proguard is throwing the following exception : 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry during packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex

**UPDATE**:

e.g. I'm using Picasso for Image loading. I've changed one file in Picasso: 
com.squareup.picasso.DeferredRequestCreator

Now, since I've changed this file, I had to include the complete Picasso library code as a modular dependency in my project.

So, my question is : How can I exclude this particular file from gradle dependency, so that I can avoid adding the complete library in my project.

Comment: You should provide more details about your build.gradle, your issue and which dependencies you would like to exclude.

Comment: Hey Gabriele, I've updated my question. Please check.

Comment: You should check the ZipException stacktrace to know which is the file that is duplicated.

Comment: The file that I have added in my project is "DeferredRequestCreator". So, its showing Duplicated for that file only. I know there is a way to exclude a module from a gradle dependency, not sure if there is a way to exclude a particular file. If there is I wan to exclude that in buil.gradle at the point where I'm defining the respective dependency, that will solve the issue as I need to edit this file.